# Set sidebar like google FAQ

Tags: html, css, sidebar

i have a question about html and css.
How can i make a sidebar like the one in [Google FAQ page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html)?
I mean, the sidebar that when you put the cursor over, an arrow appears and if you move the cursor, the arrow moves with it.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Probably done with a `:hover` css rule: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html

Comment: Marc, i thought that but i think its a little more complicated than that :)

Comment: @MarcB there is not :hover class on that div. You can inspect it with firebug to see that. It is done with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, they are listening for an event (in this case when div#gd-collapsible is hovered over) and the class "hover" is added to it.

So you have that #gd-collapsible is about 3 pixels wide and and on hover, the class "hover" is added which has 1px border solid on left and right, and that's about it really.

You can do this via jQuery, just make sure you style the div#gd-collapsible in a way that it's height equals the one from the right side bar.

Comment: I forgot the actual arrow. You could also do it via jQuery and go to the previous div where the arrow appears. From there on it's a background position that changes according to where the mouse is placed based on the Y coordinates (x stays the same).